# Verifing as a Facebook developer (Country not available under mobile registration)

Tags: facebook

I am having problems verifying my account to be a facebook developer.

http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php

> Your account must be verified before you can take this action. Please verify your account by adding your mobile phone or credit card.

When I click mobile phone I get to http://www.facebook.com/mobile/?settings

then under Register for Facebook Text Messages, the list does not include Singapore. What should I do? I dont have a credit card tho

Answer (score 2):

In fact mobile setting are only for your Facebook account (to receive alerts by SMS for example). Using this page you can't either confirm a cell number from China for example.

This is the URL you should use: http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php (this page will offer the complete list of countries).

Alternatively you can also use this page: https://www.facebook.com/update_security_info.php (Singapore is available in the list of countries), this trick was found on the link provided by @marko4o (http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16375#c126).

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to provide valid mobile number or credit card then you will be unable to verify your Developer Account.

By valid mobile number, I mean in the terms of Facebook. I have no doubt that you have a valid mobile number!

[Taken from this Facebook FAQ Article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17580)

> **How do I verify my developer account?**
>
> Facebook has several features in place
>   to limit the potential for spam and
>   abuse on the site. Verifying your
>   Facebook account helps you retain
>   control of your account and apps on
>   Facebook. There are two ways to verify
>   your account. First, you can verify
>   your cell phone, which allows us to
>   verify that a real person is in
>   control of the account. This process
>   is explained [here](http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php).
>
> The second way to verify your account
>   is to add a credit card to your
>   account. You may do so [here](https://secure.facebook.com/cards.php).
>
> Unfortunately, if you cannot verify
>   with a cell phone or add a credit
>   card, you may be unable to verify your
>   account. All developers **must be
>   verified** before they can create a
>   new app.

Comment: when I go to http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php I get "Your mobile phone has been successfully verified" but in http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php I get "Your account must be verified before you can take this action. Please verify your account by adding your mobile phone or credit card."!

Comment: @jiewmeng: It is a common recurring problem.  http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=95119

Comment: and here is the bug report http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16375